# Is there an easy way to generate ordered couples in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, foreach, range, each

I was wondering if there is something similar to the **Range** but not with integers but with ordered couples **(x, y)**. I am wondering if there is an easy way to do something like this:

```
((1,2)..(5,6)).each {|tmp| puts tmp} #=> (1,2) (3,4) (5,6)
```

**EDIT**: Maybe I was not 100% clear in my question :) I'll try to ask it in a different way.

If I had these couples: **(3,4) and (5,6)** I am looking for a way to help me generate:

```
(3,4), (4,5), (5,6)
```

if I had to exlpain it better : if the couples are (x,y)->

```
(x0,y0), ((x0+1),(y0+1)), ((x0+2), (y0+2))  and so on .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arrays as Range elements, such as:

```
> t = [1, 2]..[3, 4]
=> [1, 2]..[3, 4]
```

However, it cannot be iterated, because the `Array` class lacks a `succ` method.

```
> t.each {|tmp| puts tmp}
TypeError: can't iterate from Array
        from (irb):5:in `each'
        from (irb):5
        from D:/Programmes/Ruby/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

So if you want to allow iterating using arrays, define an `Array#succ` method that does what you want:

```
class Array
  def succ
    self.map {|elem| elem + 1 }
  end
end
```

which gives you:

```
> t = [1, 2]..[3, 4]
=> [1, 2]..[3, 4]
> t.each {|tmp| p tmp}
[1, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 4]
=> [1, 2]..[3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know that the monkey patching is not a good thing but however. Speaking of which is there a similar way to get this: [[5,4], [4,5], [3,6]] if I had [5,4] and [3,6]? It is not exactly the same logics like the first one but it has kind of the same semantics. I am jsut curious.

Comment: Why the name of the method has to be 'succ'?

Comment: @user2128702 see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Range.html#method-i-each "The each method can only be used if the begin object of the range supports the succ method.". If you want custom intermediary arrays, another approach may be required

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)

```
1.9.3-p327 :001 > (1..6).each_slice(2).to_a
 => [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't ask the question the right way I guess. There is an edit now.

Comment: Oh ok, I think SirDarius answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is an object-oriented language. So, if you want to do something with an "ordered couple object", then you need … well … an `OrderedCouple` object.

```
class OrderedCouple < Struct.new(:x, :y)
end

OrderedCouple.new(3, 4)
# => #<struct OrderedCouple x=3, y=4>
```

Uh, that looks ugly:

```
class OrderedCouple
  def to_s; "(#{x}, #{y})" end

  alias_method :inspect, :to_s

  class << self; alias_method :[], :new end
end

OrderedCouple[3, 4]
# => (3, 4)
```

`Range`s are used for two things: checking inclusion and iterating. In order for an object to be used as the start and end point of a `Range`, it has to respond to `<=>`. If you want to iterate over the `Range` as well, then the start object has to respond to `succ`:

```
class OrderedCouple
  include Comparable

  def <=>(other)
    to_a <=> other.to_a
  end

  def to_a; [x, y] end

  def succ
    self.class[x.succ, y.succ]
  end
end

puts *OrderedCouple[1, 2]..OrderedCouple[5, 6]
# (1, 2)
# (2, 3)
# (3, 4)
# (4, 5)
# (5, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
def tuples(x, y)
  return enum_for(:tuples, x, y) unless block_given?
  (0..Float::INFINITY).each { |i| yield [x + i, y + i] }
end
```

And then,

```
tuples(1,7).take(4) 
# or
tuples(1,7).take_while { |x, y| x <= 3 && y <= 9 }
```

Both return

```
[[1, 7], [2, 8], [3, 9]]
```